# Drupal - почему может не добавляться стиль?

Tags: drupal

Собственно, есть такой код в модуле, работающем на сайте с Drupal7.
Конкатенация CSS пока не применяется.

```
$module_path  = drupal_get_path('module', 'catquiz_buildin');
dpm("$module_path/css/style.css");
drupal_add_css("$module_path/css/style.css", array(
  'type' => 'file'
));
```

Но :

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/quiz/35 | grep style.css
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0@import url("http://localhost:8080/themes/garland/style.css?o6c9je");
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"garland","theme_token":"9o_4j2LOlszKFQ3pc0FlZt55tszH8Hy7GkubnrNl6ag","js":{"misc\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/catquiz_buildin\/js\/quiz-buildin.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/angular\/angular.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/quiz_api\/quiz-api.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/catquiz_buildin\/js\/quiz.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/catquiz_buildin\/css\/style.css":1,"themes\/garland\/style.css":1,"themes\/garland\/print.css":1,"themes\/garland\/fix-ie.css":1}},"quiz":{"nid":"35","uid":0,"source":"source"},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/quiz\/35?destination=quiz\/35":true}});
100  9455    0  9455    0     0  97181      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 97474
```

Т.е. в сгенерированном коде ссылки на стиль нету.

Тема оформления - немодифицированная garland из стандартной поставки.

И да - он выполняется в функции, указанной как обработчик в hook_menu